# How to add scroll up function to slideDown with 1 click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a working slideDown function which I'm using to show divs once the user clicked the button.

The divs are quite height and it would give a better overview if I would be able to scroll them to the top of the page. How can I activate and add a scroll up function to the existing slideDown function which will work simultaneously with just one click?

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#banner_step_3").hide();

  $("#next_btn_show_step_3").click(function(e){
    $("#banner_step_3").slideDown(500);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="next_btn" id="next_btn_show_step_3">
    <a href="#"><?php echo $lang ['next']; ?></a>
</div>
<article class="order_form_step_3" id="banner_step_3">
</article>
```

Comment: Just add it inside your click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jquery**

```
$("#banner_step_3").hide();
$("#next_btn_show_step_3 a").on('click', function(e) {//on link click
    var ts = $(this).attr('href');//get element
    $(ts).slideDown(500);//slide down
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(ts).offset().top }, 500);//scrollto element
    e.preventDefault();//prevent default
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="next_btn" id="next_btn_show_step_3">
    <!-- added id as href -->
    <a href="#banner_step_3">next</a>
</div>
<article class="order_form_step_3" id="banner_step_3">hey yo</article>
```

This could be made much easier if you were to post a working example.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/6ZcjK/

Comment: Thanks for your effort I appreciate it! Your example works, but when I copy/past it, the ´hide´function with #banner_step_3 doesn't seam to work correctly since that ´article´ is not hidden. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Either keep your `hide` line at the beginning like I did in the fiddle, or give it `display:none` in the css.

Answer (score 1):

Get the offset top value of the div and use jQuery .scrollTop()

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#banner_step_3").hide();
        $("#next_btn_show_step_3").click(function(e){
            $("#banner_step_3").slideDown(500, function(){
                var offsetTop = $('#banner_step_3').offset().top;
                $("html").scrollTop(offsetTop);
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```